# Reference for basic metatheory of Martin-Löf type theory

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, type-theory, formal-systems, homotopy-type-theory

Section A.4 of the HoTT book states that the metatheoretic properties of Martin-Löf type theory (such as normalization and canonicity properties) can be proved using “standard techniques from type theory.”

What is the best book to learn about these standard techniques?

Comment: What have you tried? :P

Comment: You'll probably have more luck [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com) or [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com).